# Simplifying boolean equations with K-map

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

My professor told me that I could arrive at the simplified solution using the K-map, which I guess I did, however it does not seem correct.

The equation and corresponding solution are shown in the pictures below.

My simplification steps were:

1. ABCD' + A(B' + C' + D') + (A'B'C'D') -> used two De Morgan's rules
2. A(B' + C' + D') = AB'CD + AB'CD' + ABC'D + ABC'D' + ABC'D +ABC'D' + AB'C'D + AB'C'D' + ABCD' + ABC'D + AB'CD' + AB'C'D' (opened up the brackets using the identity)
3. Draw the K-map and arrived at this simplified equation: A + AB + B'C'D' (the drawing is attached down below)

Obviously, this is incorrect, could someone help me pointing on the mistake I did and also helping to find simplification without K-map?

[image: Equation]
[image: Solution]
[image: K-map]

Comment: Did you use two rules to get to step 1? If so, what did you start with and what two rules did you apply? Or is step 1 showing us the starting point. (No, I've not spent time attempting to answer my question reading clipped images and your short summary. You should write a lot more in your question, I think. Please spend a little more time walking us through your thinking process.)

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. I am new to the website, therefore I am sorry if it appeared it was a short summary. I have included the screenshots since I couldn't find a way to write long lines on top of implicants. Yes, I did use two De Morgan's rules to get to step one. That's how I arrived at the simplification in the first step, afterwards I tried to open up brackets using the identity (A+A'=1) and then I drew the K-map including all the implicants, trying to identify the prime ones.

Comment: So we should assume you did okay in getting to step 1 and we should instead focus on why you are failing to get from there to the final answer using kmaps. But I don't see any kmaps nor any information about what you did with them to reach your final result (an error, I'm assuming.) How can we help you figure this out if we cannot see what you did to get to the wrong answer? Or are you asking us to show you the right way instead of pointing out where you went wrong?

Comment: Sorry for that. I have updated my answer, providing all the necessary information in step 2 and step 3. I have also attached the drawing of K-map that I did. My questions are: what am I doing wrong? And could anyone give me a hint how I can solve it just using the laws, rather than K-map? Since after the 1 step I feel stuck.

Comment: Huge improvement of the question. +1. I'll look it over when I get a moment. Others may jump in beforehand, though.

Comment: Thank you for having a minute.

Comment: Your kmap looks fine (developed from step 1.) And your simplification is almost where I'd naturally go, as well. It's really pretty good. I haven't checked on your step 2. But using your kmap directly I get: \$A\,\overline{B}+A\,\overline{C}+A\,\overline{D}+\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D}\$. That's actually pretty obvious by simple examination of step 1's equation, too. The first term and the last term can be merged.

Comment: Not sure how you got there. My circles are correct?

Comment: If there are merged, would it be just D'?

Comment: In my head I first circled the last column of four, just as you did. I then circled the upper-right-hand corner group of four. I then circled another four, this time picking the upper-two in the upper right hand corner, plus the bottom-two in the lower right hand corner. Finally, I circled the pair made up of the upper left hand corner one plus the upper right hand corner one. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I violated the rule that the number of squares should be the power of two. Could you give me a hint how the first and the last one can be merged in step 1, what I get is D'(ABC + A'B'C) = D'

Comment: Well, you need to take into account the middle when merging them. I'd need to draw out the entire set of logical steps for that. Are you looking to do this both algebraically as well as via kmaps? Or is seeing it through the kmap already sufficient?

Comment: I am looking to do this both algebraically as well as via k-maps, but I clearly can't see how I can merge them together.

Comment: I can provide a brute-force but also simple to understand (not tricky) way of reaching the algebraic answer. Do you want me to write up an answer for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the initial k-map:

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
&\overline{A}\:\overline{B}&\overline{A}\: B&A\: B&A\: \overline{B}\\
\hline
\overline{C}\:\overline{D}&1&0&1&1\\
\overline{C}\:D&0&0&1&1\\
C\: D&0&0&0&1\\
C\:\overline{D}&0&0&1&1
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}
$$

And here's how I circled things (using Paint):

[image]

A brute force algebra method might go like this:

$$\begin{align*}
& A\,B\,C\,\overline{D} + A\left(\overline{B} + \overline{C} + \overline{D}\right) + \overline{A}\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D}\\\\
& A\,B\,C\,\overline{D} + \overline{A}\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\,\overline{B} + A\,\overline{C} + A\,\overline{D}\\\\
& A\,B\,C\,\overline{D} + \overline{A}\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D}\\&\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad + A\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,D + A\,\overline{B}\,C\,\overline{D} + A\,\overline{B}\,C\,D\\&\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad + A\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,D + A\,B\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\,B\,\overline{C}\,D\\&\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad + A\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\,\overline{B}\,C\,\overline{D} + A\,B\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\,B\,C\,\overline{D}\\\\
& A\,B\,C\,\overline{D} + \left(\overline{A}\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D}\right.\\&\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad + \left.A\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D}\right) + A\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,D + A\,\overline{B}\,C\,\overline{D} + A\,\overline{B}\,C\,D\\&\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad + A\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,D + A\,B\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\,B\,\overline{C}\,D\\&\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad + A\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\,\overline{B}\,C\,\overline{D} + A\,B\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\,B\,C\,\overline{D}\\\\
& \overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D}\\&\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad + A\,B\,C\,\overline{D} + A\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,D + A\,\overline{B}\,C\,\overline{D} + A\,\overline{B}\,C\,D\\&\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad + A\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,D + A\,B\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\,B\,\overline{C}\,D\\&\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad + A\,\overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\,\overline{B}\,C\,\overline{D} + A\,B\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\,B\,C\,\overline{D}\\\\
& \overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\left(\overline{B}\left[\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + \overline{C}\,D + C\,\overline{D} + C\,D\right] + B\left[\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + \overline{C}\,D + C\,\overline{D}\right]\right)\\\\
& \overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\left(\overline{B} + B\left[\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + \overline{C}\,D + C\,\overline{D}\right]\right)\\\\
& \overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\left(\overline{B} + \overline{C}\,\overline{D} + \overline{C}\,D + C\,\overline{D}\right)\\\\
& \overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\left(\overline{B} + \overline{C} + C\,\overline{D}\right)\\\\
& \overline{B}\,\overline{C}\,\overline{D} + A\left(\overline{B} + \overline{C} + \overline{D}\right)
\end{align*}$$

I hope you follow those steps okay.

Comment: Thank you so much. I see where I actually did the mistake.

Comment: @Maria Glad it helped. If this solves the problem, feel free to check the answer as "accepted." This lets others know that they don't need to waste their time adding more answers. But if you think other answers might help, you should hold back on that and just wait to see.